# Testcontainers for .NET cannot detect the Docker endpoint on Azure Devops

Tags: .net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, testcontainers

Recently, at work, my team took a look into the very promising [Testcontainers for .NET](https://dotnet.testcontainers.org/) library.

The [Demo Project in GitHub](https://github.com/marpet91/testcontainers-demo) shows the simple tests that work perfectly well in any IDE and on the CLI.

But when running in Azure Devops, we get this error:

```
System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (Cannot detect the Docker endpoint. Use either the environment variables or the ~/.testcontainers.properties file to customize your configuration:
    https://dotnet.testcontainers.org/custom_configuration/ (Parameter 'DockerEndpointAuthConfig')) (The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: SqlServerWebApplicationFactory factory)
    ---- System.ArgumentException : Cannot detect the Docker endpoint. Use either the environment variables or the ~/.testcontainers.properties file to customize your configuration:
    https://dotnet.testcontainers.org/custom_configuration/ (Parameter 'DockerEndpointAuthConfig')
    ---- The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: SqlServerWebApplicationFactory factory
```

This is the pipeline executing build and tests:

```
trigger:
- master

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

jobs:
  - job: BuildAndTest
    displayName: "Solution Build and Test"
    pool:
      name: 'Default'

    steps:
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: 'Use .NET SDK 7.x'
      inputs:
        packageType: sdk
        version: '7.0.x'
    
    - script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
      displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
    
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'Execute Tests'
      inputs:
        command: test
        projects: '**/*Tests/*.csproj'
        arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
```

Is there anything missing in the pipeline yaml file or the integration test configuration?

I'm aware that there are some similar posts like [Run dotnet tests in docker which use testcontainers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75082835/run-dotnet-tests-in-docker-which-use-testcontainers) and [Testcontainers for .NET error Auto discovery did not detect a Docker host configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76039290/testcontainers-for-net-error-auto-discovery-did-not-detect-a-docker-host-config), but our demo project is different since it does not try to run the tests during docker build or docker in docker.

Comment: I had a similar issue in Bitbucket Pipelines and needed to add `services: - docker`.

Comment: @Pete did you find a fix for this?

Comment: @Ports no, still have this problem...